# Maximum sound pressure

Tags: learning, theory

Can someone explain this please?

The dynamic range that can be represented by a 32-bit (floating point) file is 1528 dB. Since the greatest difference in sound pressure on Earth can be about 210 dB, from anechoic chamber to massive shockwave, 1528 dB is far beyond what will ever be required to represent acoustical sound amplitude in a computer file.

thank you!

Comment: What is it you need an explanation of? What you are asking is not clear.

Comment: https://www.sounddevices.com/32-bit-float-files-explained/